# Do Contacts in the Auto-Suppression lists or Global Suppression List count towards Contact Limit?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, limits, suppressionlist, autosuppressionlist

Wondering if anyone knows if the contacts in Auto-Suppression lists count towards the Contact Limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They do NOT.

Auto-Suppression Configurations are indeed Sendable Data Extensions, connected by the field "emailAddress" as Subscriber Key.

Sendable Data Extensions create contacts *once you send to them*, because that action puts the contact onto All Subscribers - which is taken into account for Contact Count.

That is obviously never the case when your Sendable DE is an *auto-suppression configuration* which you cannot send to, but which in turn *cancels* other sendouts.

The only Data Extensions that count *once you import to them*, are the Synchronized Contact, Lead and User DEs from MC Connect.

I have a newly setup system in front of me with no productive sends done, and just ran the contact report:

[image]

There are around 750 contacts.

My autosuppressions in that system already contain tens of thousands of records because we use them to block legacy bounces and unsubscribes from the older sendout system:

[image]

Clearly, these at least 16k records do NOT show up in the Contact count.

Comment: If one email is sent to the contact and then it is added to the auto- suppression list. Still, it will not be counted against the Contact limit in Marketing Cloud?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: it becomes a contact upon send. adding to an auto suppression does not remove that contact.